# Validate an email address in the URL

Tags: php, preg-match, email-validation

I will validate this URL with an email address inside.

These two domains are allowed:

- `https://www.example.com/secure/index.php?ID=john@example.com`
- `https://www.example.com/secure/index.php?ID=john@example-test.com`

All names before the `@` in the email address allowed.

When the user inserts another domain after the `@`, like this:

```
https://www.example.com/secure/index.php?ID=john@gmail.com
```

they will get an error. How can I do this?

Comment: 1) please explain in more detail what are you trying to achieve. 2) add the code you have tried or at least an approach that you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$email = $_GET['ID']; // remember to filter this!
$regex = '#\w+@(?<domain>\w+\-?\w+\.\w+)#';

preg_match($regex, $email, $matches);
$domain = $matches['domain'];

if ($domain !== 'example-test.com') {
    // Unauthorised
}
```

See a working example here https://3v4l.org/SorhQ
See the regex and tweak if required here https://regex101.com/r/uDzOzm/1/

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the simple explode method to extract the domain name. see the code.

```
$parts = explode("@", "johndoe@domain.com");
$domain = $parts[1];
if(!in_array($domain, array('domain.com')))
{
    //Redirect it wherever you want
}
```

Comment: His question has a preg_match tag, he's looking for a regex solution

Answer (score 0):

You can do it:

```
if (isset($_GET['ID'])) {        
    $domain_name = substr(strrchr($_GET['ID'], "@"), 1);        
    if ($domain_name != "example-test.com"){
        Forbidden....
    }
}
```